# Add Custom Attribute to PDF Invoice

Tags: invoice, pdf

I want to add the warehouse location (Custom attribute) as a column in each product in the PDF Invoice. I googled and i found exactly what i was looking for [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/)! I think that the code its pretty outdated as it is from 2011 and maybe magento changed from then. I noticed that those files are now not located in /Model/Order/Pdf/... but in /Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/...
My magento setup is some years old and i made some more changed in the PDF Invoice in the past so maybe that cause the problem. 
Anyway when trying to use this code and Print the invoice i receive the following error and i don't really get it. Can you please point me out?

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/xxxxxx/WarehouseLocationToInvoice/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php, line 1

Trace:
#0 /home/.../public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(1065): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true)
#2 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php(121): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice2015-10-...', '%PDF-1.4\n%\xE2\xE3\xCF\xD3\n...', 'application/pdf')
#3 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php(489): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice->printAction()
#4 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController->printAction()
#5 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('print')
#6 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /home/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /home/.../public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /home/.../public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the answer. I convert the File Encoding of those 2 files to "windows-1253" and its working fine now.